# WebAPI - config.EnableQueryOptions is marked as depreciated what is the gudance now?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am building a WebAPI 2 project, and I like the Idea of enabling OData query support.  Done by including the Odata nuget package and enabling it via `config.EnableQeyOptions()`

I notice that this method is marked as depreciated but cant find out what we should use instead.  Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to this nugget package
Microsoft.AspNet.Odata

Then sample code could look like this

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // New code:
    ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    builder.EntitySet<Product>("Products");
    config.MapODataServiceRoute(
        routeName: "ODataRoute",
        routePrefix: null,
        model: builder.GetEdmModel());
}
```

you can find the full post here
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint

Comment: so is EnableQueryOption depreciated since Odata controllers became available?

Comment: honestly I am not sure, I have not yet seen text that has stated that, I just know this to be the "new" way to do it.